# Do we have Force.com Toolkit for SAP?

Tags: integration

Do we have Force.com toolkit for SAP? i know we have Force.com Toolkit for PHP and .net and also for java. How could SAP access the SFDC API without a toolkit? If anything exists please share the knowledge.

Thanks,
Baskaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no force.com toolkit for SAP. The way to connect from SAP to SF would be to use any of the Salesforce API's (Webservice API, Rest API, etc). 
E.g. for Webservice API follow these steps:

- produce the appropriate WSDL from Salesforce
  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm|SkinName=webhelp
- and generate stub classes in SAP ABAP from it, as described here e.g.: http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Consuming+Web+Services+with+ABAP+-+WSDL.